# Transpose multiple columns into 2 column and single row to multiple row in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Using `Select top 1` statement I have to retrieve data from an 8 column table without any unique key.  Now I want to transpose this table into two columns: original column name to the first and its respective value to second.

An original table like this:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 
55      | 108     | 555     | 85
```

And the expected result:

```
ColumnName | Value
Column1    | 55
Column2    | 108
Column3    | 555
Column4    | 85
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a T-SQL construct called `UNPIVOT` which is designed for this. But in my experience, you'll have more luck with `APPLY` as per my code below:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 'Col1', Column1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Col2', Column2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Col3', Column3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Col4', Column4
   ) u (columnName, Value)
  ;
```

Comment: Thank you
instead of Select * From YourTable t
which add two more columns (columnName and Value) to original select statement

Select u.columnName, u.Value from YourTable t
CROSS Apply(...............);
does a perfect job.

Comment: Does not work for me, there is an error indicating SELECT is on the wrong place, apparently....probably something with the syntax. I am using MySQL however.

Comment: I can’t guarantee this will work in MySQL. The syntax is valid in SQL Server though.